# Strange behaviour with nested TestConfiguration in Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I have a simple project where Im trying to override a bean in the nested `@TestConfiguration` class. However strangely, even though it is nested within the class the Bean is loaded when running tests in other classes.

So for instance I have,

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DummyService {
    private DummyClient dummyClient;

    public DummyService(DummyClient dummyClient) {
        this.dummyClient = dummyClient;
    }
}
```

In my tests, `TestA`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, properties = {"grpc.port=7889"})
@Slf4j
public class TestA {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DummyService dummyService(DummyClient dummyClient) throws Exception {
            DummyClient dummyClientSpied = spy(dummyClient);
            JsonObject jsonObject = responseAsJson("test.json");
            doReturn(Optional.of(jsonObject)).when(dummyClientSpied).doHttpGet(anyString());
            return new DummyService(dummyClientSpied);
        }
    }

    // Test methods
    // ....
}
```

Another test class `TestB`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, properties = {"grpc.port=7895"})
@Slf4j
public class TestB {

    @Autowired
    private DummyService dummyService; // <--- Seems to be the Bean with the spied DummyClient

    // Test methods
    // ....
}
```

I cant quite figure out why the bean defined in the nested `@TestConfiguration` is getting loaded in `TestB`. Any help is appreciated.